# Java Play 2.2.6 : index.scala.html update not reflecting in controller.Application

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, playframework

I am new to Java Play and am working with version 2.2.6 as I'm on a windows machine and was unable to get the newest version working correctly.

I am working through the tutorial for version 2.2.6, [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaTodoList#rendering-the-first-page), and have encountered a problem in the section called "Rendering the First Page," located approximately two thirds of the way down in the tutorial.

The tutorial shows how to make a simple "to do list" application in Java Play which has a Form where the user can submit "to do" items, which then appear on screen, and also delete them.

In "Rendering the First Page," the tutorial instructs the user to add the following code to the controller "Application.java" :

```
public static Result tasks(){
    return ok(views.html.index.render(models.Task.all(), taskForm);
}
```

So, at this point, my Application.java looks like this:

```
package controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.Task;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.data.*;
import models.*;

import views.html.*;

public class Application extends Controller {

    static Form<Task> taskForm = Form.form(Task.class);

  public static Result index() {
    return ok("Hello World");
  }

  public static Result tasks() {
        return ok(
                views.html.index.render(models.Tasks.all(), taskForm)
                );
      }


  public static Result newTask() {
        return TODO;
      }

  public static Result deleteTask(Long id) {
        return TODO;
      }
}
```

Eclipse immediately underlines the word "render" in red, and I get the following error when I hover over it: "the method render(String) in the type index is not applicable for the arguments (List, Form)"

The tutorial had me create a model called Task.java, and if you look at the top of Application.java, it also had me "import com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.Task," which I'm not really sure what it does.

Here's my model, Task.java:

```
package models;

import java.util.*;

import play.data.validation.Constraints.*;

public class Task {

    public Long id;

    @Required
    public String label;

    public static List<Task> all(){
        return new ArrayList<Task>();
    }

    public static void create(Task task){

    }

    public static void delete(Long id){

    }
}
```

So, all that being said, here's what I think the problem is:

"render"'s parameter(s) is/are defined in the view "index.scala.html", in scala

When you first create a blank Java application in java play, it auto-fills index.scala.html with the following lines of code:

```
@(message: String)

@main("Welcome to Play") {

    @play20.welcome(message, style = "Java")

}
```

The tutorial had me delete all of that from index.scala.html, which like I said is a view, and had me replace it with this code:

```
@(tasks: List[Task], taskForm: Form[Task])

@import helper._

@main("Todo list") {

    <h1>@tasks.size() task(s)</h1>

    <ul>
        @for(task <- tasks) {
            <li>
                @task.label

                @form(routes.Application.deleteTask(task.id)) {
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
                }
            </li>
        }
    </ul>

    <h2>Add a new task</h2>

    @form(routes.Application.newTask()) {

        @inputText(taskForm("label")) 

        <input type="submit" value="Create">

    }

}
```

Now, the very first line in index.scala.html is what tells the controller what params "render" takes. As you can see, when you make a blank Java Play application, it starts out being @(message: String). I changed it to be @(tasks: List[Task], taskForm[Task]). So it should know that those are the params that "render" should take. But for some reason, it still thinks that "render" is supposed to take a String, and gives me an error.

I've been scouring the internet for hours and tried many solutions that have been offered before posting my own question.

Here's some things I've tried:

1. adding these lines to build.sbt (with spaces in between):

   EclipseKeys.projectFlavor := EclipseProjectFlavor.Java
   EclipseKeys.preTasks := Seq(compile in Compile)

and then closing out eclipse. from the command line in my project's directory, running "play clean-all" "play compile" "play eclipse", and then re-importing the project into eclipse.

2. refreshing everything in eclipse
3. ignoring the error and running "play debug run" and then going to localhost:9000 (one person said that this happened to them and that they just ignored the error in the IDE and that it worked fine on the server), but instead I just got the same error at localhost as I got in Eclipse, which I screen shotted:

[image: scalaerror]

At this point I have no idea how to proceed. My best guess like I said is that the problem is that the application for some reason doesn't "know" that I updated "index.scala.html" thereby changing the parameters that "render" takes, but I don't know why it doesn't "know" it.

Sorry this was so long; I wanted to make sure I'd included everything.

If anyone has any ideas that would be great, thank you.

Comment: If new to Play better to start with the latest version 2.6

Answer (score 0):

in your controller you're importing a javafx Task class:

```
import com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.Task;
```

but your view is expect your model class:

```
models.Task
```

change javafx Task import to models.Task import.